# How to fetch additional parameters from a url which is rewritten using .htaccess & mod rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have over 2500 urls which is rewritten using mod_rewrite. They are as below:

```
^abc$ page.php?param1=poi&param2=xsd
^xyz$ page.php?param1=ljk&param2=qwe
```

Now if i pass additional parameters from the rewritten url, like,

```
domain.com/abc&extra=qwerty
```

i am unable to fetch them using the code below using

```
if($_GET['extra']<>''){
    $extra = $_GET['extra'];
}
```

Also, domain.com/abc&extra=qwerty is redirecting me to my 404 error page.

Comment: Please add your full mod_rewrite configuration.  How you defined ^abc$ might be related.  Did you use REQUEST_URI?  What RewriteCond did you specify before (if any)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `/abc?extra=qwerty` and add QSA in your htaccess rules like this :

```
^abc$ page.php?param1=poi&param2=xsd [QSA]
^xyz$ page.php?param1=ljk&param2=qwe [QSA]
```